# Not able to open app on few android devices

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic` I am using `ng-cordova.min.js` in `www/js` folder and it's working fine on system and my phone too but when I am installing on any other android device, a white screen is appearing with the error

> Failed to load resource:net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://android_asset/www/js/ng-cordova.min.js

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: h solved this error by using "bower install ngcordova" and declaring the .js file in index.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by using "bower install ngcordova" and declaring the .js file in index.html –  Sudhakar Rapeti just now   edit